# How to run useEffect once even if there are dependencies? And why ESLint is complaining about it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following example:

```
const userRole = sessionStorage.getItem('role');
const { data, setData, type, setTableType } = useTable([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    // fetch some data from API
    const fetchedData = await axios('..');
    
    if (userRole === 'admin') {
     setData([...fetchedData, { orders: [] }]);
    } else {
     setData(fetchedData);
    }
    
    if (type === '1') {
     setTableType('normal');
    }
  };
  getData();
}, []);
```

I want to run this effect ONLY on mounting and that's it, I don't care whether the `userRole` or `setData` has changed or not!

So, Now my questions are:

1. Why ESLint is complaining about `userRole` being missing in the
   dependencies array? Its not even a state!
2. Why ESLint is
   complaining about `setData` being missing in the dependencies array
   isn't it will always be the same reference or does it change?
3. How to achieve what I want without upsetting the linter? Or should I straight slap the good old `// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` line? Or this is absolutely barbaric?
4. Why this indicates a bug in my code? I want to run this effect only
   once with whatever is available initially.

EDIT:
Let me rephrase the question What If these variables change and I don't care about their new values? Especially when `type` is getting updated in different places in the same file. I just want to read the initial value and run useEffect once how to achieve that?

> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning

Comment: If `userRole` changes, won't the data be incorrect then?

Comment: @RossAllen `userRole` is stored in sessionStorage and it will always be the same unless the user logged out and logged in with different account type

Comment: Yes, #3, yes. Always been doing this

Comment: "unless the user logged out and logged in with different account type" <- this is why `userRole` should be in the dependencies array. The code doesn't know the business logic of "it will always be the same".

Comment: Also, the eslint rule is aware that the second value returned from `React.useState` does not change over time, but `useTable` appears to be a custom library; it doesn't know anything special about `setData` and so gives you the same warning as any other variable.

Comment: @RossAllen Same goes for any variable. I stated clearly that I don't care about whether the variables change or not I want to run `useEffect` once like `componentDidMount `without upsetting the linter.

Comment: @RossAllen the `useTable` is a custom hook I wrote which has `state` and `setState` and other functions that I expose.

Comment: If these things don't change over time then the `useEffect` will only get called once. If these things ever do change, your code will be logically incorrect and will lead to subtle errors. I suggest following the lint rule; it is helping you here and preventing subtle potential bugs.

Comment: @RossAllen Ok let me rephrase the question what If they do change and I don't care? I just want to read the initial value and run useEffect once how to achieve that?

Comment: You already answered that in 3., right? "// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps". These rules are correctly identifying that the logic in your code is incorrect though. Ignoring this warning means you might ignore it in the future and your code _will_ be incorrect when those values change. The fact that you know they won't change is fine; then the `useEffect` will only ever run one time like you want. If you add the vals to the array, your code will then also be logically correct.

Comment: @RossAllen Exactly! I intentionally want to run this piece of code only once on mounting even if any of these variables change, I updated the question with another variable `type` to help delivering my point. This `type` changes whenever the user clicks on a button to go to the next table. In this case If I added the `type` to dependency array it will get triggered which what I don't want! Can you check the post one last time and tell me what do you think?

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to create a hook for initializing (running once).

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useInit = initCallback => {
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

  if (!initialized) {
    initCallback();
    setInitialized(true);
  }
};
```

Then use it on you React components:

```js
useInit(() => {
  // Your code here will be run only once
});
```

Comment: This seems the cleanest approach to me

Comment: Is it possible to still do effect cleanup?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: After an update to React, it seems Eslint has begun complaining about the below solution, so I'd probably use `// eslint-disable-line`

Note: This answer is not written with React 18's double useEffect in mind.

---

You're correct in that giving `useEffect` an empty dependencies array is the way to go if you want the effect to run only once when the component mounts. The issue that ESLint is warning you about is the potential for the effect to execute using stale data, since it references external state properties, but as you've noticed, giving the array the dependencies it asks for causes the effect to run whenever any of them changes as well.

Luckily there is a simple solution that I'm surprised hasn't been yet mentioned — wrap the effect in a `useCallback`. You can give the dependencies to `useCallback` safely without it executing again.

```js
// Some state value
const [state, setState] = useState();

const init = useCallback(
  () => {
    // Do something which references the state
    if (state === null) {}
  }, 
  // Pass the dependency to the array as normal
  [state]
);

// Now do the effect without any dependencies
useEffect(init, []);
```

Now `init` will re-memoize when a dependency changes, but unless you call it in other places, it will only actually be called for execution in the `useEffect` below.

To answer your specific questions:

1. ESLint complains about `userRole` because React components re-run for every render, meaning `userRole` could have a different value in the future. You can avoid this by moving `userRole` outside your function.
2. Same as previous case, although `setData` may realistically always the same, the potential for it to change exists, which is why ESLint wants you to include it as a dependency. Since it is part of a custom hook, this one cannot be moved outside your function, and you should probably include it in the dependencies array.
3. See my primary answer
4. As I may have already explained in the first 2, ESLint will suspect this to be a bug due to the fact that these values have the potential to change, even if they don't actually do so. It may just be that ESLint doesn't have a special case for checking "on mount" effects, and thus if it checks that effect like any other effect which may trigger several times, this would clearly become a realistic bug. In general, I don't think you need to worry too much about dependency warnings if your effect runs only once and you know the data is correct at that time.

Comment: You still have to pass `init` to the useEffect dep array in order to satisfy `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`, so this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Kraken Yes, I added a note at the top of the answer on Jun 9, 2022. Before that, `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` didn't warn about it, which in hindsight was probably a bug rather than a feature.

Answer (score 3):

1. User role is in the `useEffect` thus it's a dependency (if it will change - the `useEffect` is invalid)
2. the `useEffect` doesn't know if it will be the same or not, that's why it's asking for a dependency
3. Usually do what the linter is asking, and add those two in the dependency array.

```
const userRole = sessionStorage.getItem('role');
const { data, setData } = useTable([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    // fetch some data from API
    const fetchedData = await axios('..');
    
    if (userRole === 'admin') {
     setData([...fetchedData, { orders: [] }]);
    } else {
     setData(fetchedData);
    }
  };
  getData();
}, [userRole, setData]);
```

4. [here's Dan Abramov's take on this](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#what-happens-when-dependencies-lie)

> “But I only want to run it on mount!”, you’ll say. For now, remember: if you specify deps, all values from inside your component that are used by the effect must be there. Including props, state, functions — anything in your component.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but let me rephrase my question: What If they do change and I don't care? I just want to read the initial value and run useEffect once how to achieve that?

Comment: is `userRole` used anywhere else in the app ?

Comment: @Mohamed move `const userRole = sessionStorage.getItem('role');` outside the component body, or do `const [userRole] = useState(sessionStorage.getItem('role'));` The former will allow you to omit `userRole` from the dependencies list, while the latter still requires you to include it in the dependencies list, but the `useEffect()` won't rerun if the sessionStorage updates in between renders of the component.

Comment: @Mohamed sorry, misspoke, do you use it anywhere in this component? if not, you can just put it in the `useEffect` hook, and that's it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Actually this will solve the userRole issue correct let me add another variable to deliver my point.

Comment: @k.s. Yes you're correct as well I just wanted to deliver a point let me edit the post

Comment: @Mohamed you need to add both `setTableType` and `type`  to the `useEffect` dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Linting is a process of analyzing code for potential errors. Now when we talk about why do we get a lint error, we need to understand that the rules were set by keeping in mind the ideal use cases of particular functionality.

Here incase of a useEffect hook, the general notion says that if we have a value which might change or which might lead to a change in logic flow, all those should go into the dependencies array.

So, data is the first candidate to go in. Similar is the case with userRole as it is being used to control the logic flow and not simply as a value.

Going with linter suggestion to ignore the error is what I recommend.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! But going with what the linter wants will trigger useEffect to run whenever any of the variables inside the dependency array change! Which what I don't want!

Comment: Correct me if am wrong but you want to know of a way to solve all flags raised by linter not by commenting it out but my using the dependency array BUT want it to run only once?

Comment: Yes! I want to leave the dependency array empty to make the useEffect run only once without making the linter angry

Comment: Since you are using a custom hook am not sure on how to make the linter happy but run it only once. However, there exists a hackish way (useRef) to keep your array non-empty and run it once and hence keeping the linter happy. Though I would suggest against it.

Comment: I'm looking for the correct way to do it since I'm very confused and the documentation doesn't mention this case!

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat: I do not suggest actually using this. This is implementing incorrect logic and is *guaranteed* to be wrong when a value changes. The linter is trying to help because the code below introduces many subtle bugs.**

If you want to do this though, you could use a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to store the one-time function:

```js
const userRole = sessionStorage.getItem('role');
const { data, setData, type, setTableType } = useTable([]);

const _dangerousOnMount = useRef(async () => {
  // fetch some data from API
  const fetchedData = await axios('..');
  
  if (userRole === 'admin') {
    setData([...fetchedData, { orders: [] }]);
  } else {
    setData(fetchedData);
  }
  
  if (type === '1') {
    setTableType('normal');
  }
});

useEffect(() => {
  _dangerousOnMount.current();
}, []);
```

Comment: Hmm this seems kinda hacky to me I was looking for a more clear way to do it but you gave me a very good advice "If these things don't change over time then the useEffect will only get called once. If these things ever do change, your code will be logically incorrect and will lead to subtle errors. I suggest following the lint rule; it is helping you here and preventing subtle potential bugs" I appreciate it really.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try to create a custom hook that can solve this problem.

```js
  const useMountEffect = () =>
    useEffect(() => {
      // Your code that has dependencies
    }, []);

  useMountEffect();
```

This way, the code runs exactly once even if the dependencies change and the component re-renders. This solves the issue with the es-lint as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using reactive values, which include props and all variables and functions declared directly inside of your component. To remove a dependency, you will need to prove that it’s not a dependency. In other words, all props, variables and functions need to be hardcoded as a const that will never change.

This will make your code more understandable since it is no longer using dependency variables that may or may not change.

Refer to https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#removing-unnecessary-dependencies